# Counting solutions of $x^{30}=1$ in $S_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

> I was asked to count the number of solution of $$x^{30} =1$$ with $x \in S_{6}$     (the group of the permutations over a set with $6$ elements).

I started noticing that the divisors of $30$ are: $1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30$ so I have to count all the permutations of order one divisor of $30$. During the counting I use the fact that every permutations has an unique factorization in disjoint cycles.

So I'm starting counting the number of permutations of order $2$.

We have $15$ different $ 2 -$cycle, $45$ way to combine $2$ disjoint $ 2-$cycles and $15$ way to combine $3$ disjoint $2-$cycles. We don't have any other elements of,order $2$ in $S_6$.

Order $3$ is similar, we have $40$ different $3-$cycles and $40$ different products of $2$ disjoint $3-$cycles.

Of order $5$ we have only the $5-$cycles ( $144$) and nothing else because we are in $S_6$.

Of order $6$ we have $120$ different $6-$cycles and $120$ way to compose a $3-$cycle with a disjoint $2-$cycle.

I didn't found elements of order $10,15,30$ because we need at least $S_7$ to have an element of order $10$ ( a $2-$cycle composed with a  disjoint $5-$cycle)

So in total I counted $ 539+1=540$ solution of the equation. To count every case I use a combinatorial approach.

Is my reasoning correct? Is there a faster (and more group-related let's say) way to count the solutions in this case?

I thought about the orbit-stabilizer theorem but I had problems calculating the size of the stabilizer of every conjugation class.
Thanks in advance :)

NOTE: I've redone all my calculations and now are correct :) still the best methods are the ones,explained in the answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*Disclaimer*: The following is a complete solution to the question. Continue reading if you're looking for a complete solution.]

We have $x^{30}\ne 1$ iff $x$ contains a cycle whose length does not divide $30$. Possible cycle lengths are $1$, $\ldots$, $6$, among which only $4$ does not divide $30$.

You can choose a four-cycle in ${6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\over4}=90$ ways, and the remaining two elements can either stay fixed or be combined to a $2$-cycle. It follows that there are $180$ permutations in $S_6$ with $x^{30}\ne1$; therefore the remaining $540$ permutations $x$ satisfy $x^{30}=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you tell me please what kind of permutations I didn't count in my resolution of the exercise?

Comment: @RicPed For starters, there are six times more $5$-cycles than the $24$ you counted.  That's the bulk of the discrepancy, and chances are there are other miscounts in your calculations.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I made these calculations :(

Comment: So theoretically I have counted all the permutations? Without the miscalculations are the count correct? Or I have forgotten one kind of permutation?

Comment: @YACP: I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter No, don't do that! It is OK to give full solutions for other interested people. Leave it to us to choose which solution we like best. There is no point in throwing a good answer to the trash! =/

Answer (score 4):

It is simplier to count the number of solutions of $x^{30}\ne 1$. Since the order of a permutation equals to lcm of lengths of its cycles, then $x$ must be of the form either $(....)$ or  $(..)(....)$ (then it orders is divided by $4$). Their number is $2\cdot С^4_6\cdot P_3$ (here $C^m_n$ is the  binomial coefficient, $P_n$ is the number of permutations).

Comment: Aren't there more $4$-cycles than there are $4$-subsets?  (assuming $C_6^4$ means the binomial coefficient, that is).

Comment: @Erick Wong: Thank you, certainly. I was mistaken.

Comment: How do you obtain such formula? Thanks for,the answer :)

Comment: @Ric Ped: We can choose $4$ elements by $C^4_6$ ways. Then to get all 4-cycles we have to fix an element from them and to permute the rests (by $P_3=3! ways).

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can find the number of solutions machinery. GAP helps to find it as follows:

```
 > S6:=SymmetricGroup(6);;
 > Size(Union(Filtered(S6,x-> Order(x)=1),Filtered(S6,x-> Order(x)=2),Filtered(S6,x-> Order(x)=3),Filtered(S6,x-> Order(x)=6),Filtered(S6,x-> Order(x)=5)));

 > 540
```

---

Regarding to @Alexander's neat comment: you can do it also by:

```
 > S6:=SymmetricGroup(6);;
 > Size(Filtered(S6,x-> Order(x) in [1,2,3,5,6]));
 > 540
```

or

```
 > Number(Filtered(S6,x-> Order(x) in [1,2,3,5,6]));      
 > 540
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it's time to start using GAP for me:)

Comment: Gap, indeed! (Me, too, @RicPed !)

Comment: Thanks! Though for $S_6$ this may not give a visible speedup, since  the provided command does it fast enough, for a general case this may be improved by: (1) Considering conjugacy classes, since the order of an element is their invariant; (2) counting numbers and then summing them instead of forming the union; (3) doing all in one pass checking for a conjugacy class representative `x` that `Order(x) in [1,2,3,5,6]`

Comment: There is a typo (parentheses do not match). What about `Number(S6,x-> Order(x) in [1,2,3,5,6]);` then? As for the conjugacy classes representatives, that may be left as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: P.S. Just to explain what `Number` does - it may be viewed as a shortcut to `Length(Filtered(...`, so there is no need to write `Number(Filtered(...`. Under the hood, `Length(Filtered(...` would create another list at an intermediate step and thus use more memory, while `Number(...` will **iterate** over the list that already exists.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I see. In fact, this is the differences between using `Number(...)` and `Lenght(...)`. Can one find some differences between `Size(...)` and `Order(...)` as well? Or they act the same? Thanks for the rain of coded gifts. :)

Comment: `Size` is installed as a method for `Order` in cases where this is appropriate: enter e.g. `ApplicableMethod(Order,[SymmetricGroup(3)]);` to see this.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I feel GAP properly in this time. Dear Prof. Konovalov, I don't think someone could find these points at once. Why don't we find a concrete source in which one can be taught these issues? I think we need a book in this area. :)