# Find permutations whose third power is known

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

I have to find permutations $a$ such that $a^3=(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)(5 \ 6)(7 \ 8 \ 9 \  10)$
 and I have to find at least 3 solutions.

So first I must find disjoint cycles.
                    Those are: 
 1 [2,2,2][4]      and   2 [4,2][4]  and 3[6][4] 
are there any more cycles?
and what is the order of numbers (1,2,3,...10) in those new cycles?
so is solution (1 2)(3 4)(5 6)(7 10 9 8) sufficient for 1 and (1 3 2 4)(5 6)(7 10 9 8) for 2?

Comment: Why this closing proposal  ? This asker has done personal work on a question that is (almost) clearly settled.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have no idea and I have voted to leave it open.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your first sentence and your title : this is for attracting ... and retaining readers later on.

Comment: @jose how do you "vote to leave it open" before it's actually closed?  Sometimes I want to prevent a question from being closed but feel powerless unless the question gets closed/on hold and I have to vote to reopen

Comment: @OscarLanzi Because the question appeared to me in the **close votes** review queue.

Comment: Does that require 160k rep to see?

Answer (score 1):

Yes for $p=(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)(5 \ 6)(10 \ 9 \ 8 \ 7)$.

No for $p=(1 \ 3 \ 2 \ 4)(5 \ 6)(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)$ ; it isn't a solution because $p^3$ would send $1$ onto $4$ instead of $2$.

---

Here is a way to find many solutions :

First, as you have well seen it, we must take for the last cycle $\color{red}{the \ reversed \  cycle \ (7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$ (because for a cycle $c$ on 4 elements, $c^4=id \ \iff \ (c^{-1})^3=c$, and there are no other solutions).

A first global solution is :

$$ (1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)(5 \ 6)\color{red}{(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$$

(You had recognized it). Please note that we use the fact that a transposition $t$ is such that $t^3=t$.

A family of 8 other solutions are found by considering an order-$6$ cycle on elements $1 \cdots 6$ :

$$ (\underline{1} \ 3 \ 6 \ \underline{2} \ 4 \ 5)\color{red}{(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$$

$$ (\underline{1} \ 4 \ 6 \ \underline{2} \ 3 \ 5)\color{red}{(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$$

$$ (\underline{1} \ 5 \ 3 \ \underline{2} \ 6 \ 4)\color{red}{(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$$

$$ (\underline{1} \ 6 \ 3 \ \underline{2} \ 5 \ 4)\color{red}{(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$$

$$ (\underline{1} \ 3 \ 5 \ \underline{2} \ 4 \ 6)\color{red}{(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$$

$$ (\underline{1} \ 4 \ 5 \ \underline{2} \ 3 \ 6)\color{red}{(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$$

$$ (\underline{1} \ 5 \ 5 \ \underline{2} \ 6 \ 6)\color{red}{(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$$

$$ (\underline{1} \ 6 \ 5 \ \underline{2} \ 5 \ 6)\color{red}{(7 \ 10 \ 9 \ 8)}$$

with the following building recipe :

- $1$ and $2$ must be separated by two elements,
- the same for $3$ and $4$,
- the same for $5$ and $6$.

(being understood that "separated" is by reference to a cyclic arrangement).

As the positions of $1$ and $2$ are "frozen", the choice is reduced to the $2\times2\times2 = 8$ solutions given upwards, to which we must add the exceptional first one.

**Remarks :**

a) about the necessity to gather $1,2 \cdots 6$ into a cycle :

- no solution can exist of the form $(1 a b c)(* * )$ for the reason seen upwards : we should have $p=(1 a b 2)(* *)$ but then $p^3=(1 2 a b)(* *)$ which is not what we desire.
- no solution can exist of the form $(a b c d)(1  2)$ for a similar reason.

b) As remarked by @Robert Shore, it is not evident that no other solution exists by grouping for example $7$ with other elements than $8,9,10$, even if our intimate conviction says that there none.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious (at least to me) why there can be no solution that includes a cycle of the form $(7 x \ldots) \text{ with } x \neq 8, 9, 10$.  I can see why with a little work but it's probably worth including the reasoning in the answer, particularly since such cycles would be possible if we were working within $S_{12}$ instead of $S_{10}$.

Comment: You are right, it is not obvious. I am going to try to give an explanation.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475105 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/978613